# Problem Hosting WCF Service in VB6 debug mode - unable to open its IChannelListener

Tags: wcf, vb6

So i have a WCF services that is hosted in a VB6 app via COM. The problem i have is when you debug the VB6 app the application is launched under the VB6.exe process not a separate process like Visual Studio. If i terminate the app by hitting stop in the debugger or there is an exception then the next time i run the app it tries to start the wcf host again an i get this error

The ChannelDispatcher at 'http://localhost:8080/basic' with contract(s) '"IEvalService"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.

I know this is because the ServiceHost.Abort or ServiceHost.Close is not being called in these situations. I call this when i close the app normally and it works the next time. The only way i can fix it is to restart VB.

Is there a way i can check to see if the service host is running, abort it and then start it again?

Comment: I thought you could check the ServiceHost state but you no longer have a reference to that object when you restart debugging in VB

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this"

Answer (score 0):

As far as the app crashing due to an exception: you might want to consider wrapping the main method in a try-catch and close the service if there is an exception.

As far as the ChannelDispatcher error, one way to handle it would be to put the code in a try-catch and catch specifically for this exception; in the catch block, start the service under a different port.

Comment: A try catch block only works if the exception is in .net. The problem is .net dosn't seem to realise that these application has closed because the VB IDE is still running.